# "Till now" in formal letter

Tags: word-choice, email, letter

Is it okay to use "till now" in a formal letter?

"Listing below all the changes done till now..."

or is there a better synonym I can use?

Comment: Till now? You want me to get out the ox team and plow my field right this very second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More usual phrases to use in that situation are "until now," "at this point," or "at this time". Using "till" will may the reader think 'til, which is much more conversational.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems. Till now is a very old and proper English phrase from which until derived. Shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is an ok phrase to be used, although there are many more words that would be preferable to it, such as 'before [date of change]' or 'preceding [date]'